# Android emulator will not rotate

Tags: android, android-emulator

The shortcuts for putting the Android emulator into landscape view do not work for me. Searching through related questions I see a lot of information about an old bug where the emulator would change orientations, but the rotation event would not be triggered. However, this is different, my emulator won't even change orientation (the keyboard shortcuts do nothing).

Attempting to turn off the portrait orientation in the emulator manager also does nothing, nor do any of the QEMU options relating to the display size (eg. I can't start it in fullscreen or change the geometry of the display at all).

This happens with both a 4.4 image or a 5.0 image. Keyoard support is on and works in general.

Is this a known issue, or is there some trick to getting newer versions of the Android Emulator to change orientation at all?

Comment: What shortcuts you use? Ctrl + F11 / F12 works well for me, but on some emulators orientation doesn't change when rotated: true.

Comment: I have tried Ctrl+F11 and F12. There is no rotation of qemu or orientation change in Android.